# Keras Weights Saving

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working with pretrained Keras model MobileNets. I am trying to save the weights of one of the layer in a text file. The dimension of the weight matrix is as follows:

```
      layerr = model.layers[2].get_weights()
      print(layerr.shape)

      (1, 3, 3, 3, 32)
```

I am confused as to which is the 3's corresponds to the channel and which of them corresponds to height and width. I know that the 32 corresponds to the number of filters.

Also if you could help me in saving them as a linear matrix, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is strange, `get_weights()` should be returning a list, which is not your case in this code. Anyway, assuming you're picking the correct array from the list, and assuming it's a 3D convolution... (otherwise something is not quite right and I'd ask you to share your exact layer definition).

Sounds like a 3D convolution filter with these numbers in sequence:

- 1 spatial dimension 1
- 3 spatial dimension 2
- 3 spatial dimension 3
- 3 input channels
- 32 output channels

---

There are several ways of saving a numpy array. I like `numpy.save()`.

```
np.save('filename.npy', layerr)
```

You can also create a text file and save it as text:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(layerr))
```

Not sure about what a "linear matrix" is, but if you want it with only one dimension, you can reshape:

```
flatWeights = layerr.reshape((-1,))
#then save
```

But if you're saving for using later, it's better to use `model.save()` or `model.save_weights()`.

Comment: So, the first layer in MobileNets takes input of size 224 * 224 * 3. Then a 3 * 3 * 3 3D Conv is applied and there are 32 such filters (kernels). And with a stride of 2, we have output of 112 * 112 * 32.


 The get_weights function call returns a numpy array.


 What I am trying to do is to save the 27 weight values from one filter in continuous memory, then the next 27 weight values of the second kernel following that and so on. So, I want a 27 * 32 = 864 1d array.

Comment: This is very strange. You should not be able to use Conv3D with that input. You should use Conv2D. Everything I could think of is in my answer, the rest needs that you properly show what you're doing.